# Using Angular formatters / parsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can't seem to get Angular formatters and parsers working:

**app.js:**

```
var itemApp = angular.module('itemApp', []);

itemApp.controller('ItemController', ['$scope',  function($scope) {

      $scope.some_value = 'abcEFG';

}]);

itemApp.directive('changeCase', function () {
    return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
              return value.toUpperCase();
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
              return value.toLowerCase();
            });

          }
    };
});
```

**view.html:**

```
  <input ng-model="some_value" changeCase>
```

It doesn't work- no errors, just nothing happens to the values in the input or the model. I'm newish to Angular, having trouble figuring out how I'd even debug this.

Comment: [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and all string manipulating methods do not manipulate the string in place, they return the transformed string. So you would do `return value.toUpperCase()` etc

Comment: Sorry, sloppy example code. Still doesn't work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write:

```
<input ng-model="some_value" change-case> //camel-case
```

This is explained in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> **Normalization**
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name
>   to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer
>   to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> - Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> - Convert or _-delimited name to camelCase.